# PHP and JSON get followers count

Tags: javascript, html, json

Consider a javascript code snippet, which uses **JSON to get twitter followers** count. The problem is that I get the following: 'undefined 2146 Followers'. This script is meant for printng data about 4 twitter accounts. The code is as follows:

```
<div id='twitter'>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var i;
      twitterusername = ['Sinbg','followfog','miniclip','vgames'];
      for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/users/' + twitterusername[i] +
                  '.json?callback=?', function(data){
          $('#twitter').html('' + twitterusername[i] + ' ' +
                             data.followers_count + ' Followers' + '<br/>');
        }); 
      }
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what kolink said, you're overwriting the contents of the twitter div so you only get the last output.

Here is all of it fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/fEfNr/

Answer (score 2):

When the `$('#twitter').html(...)` part gets called, your `for` loop has ended and the value of `i` is `4`. Consequently, `twitterusername[4]` is `undefined`.

To fix, structure your loop like this:

```
for( i=0; i<4; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        // your loop stuff here
    })(i);
}
```

This creates a new closure for `i`, effectively "anchoring" its value.

Comment: Tried fixing it but still not working. Could you give a JSfiddle example?

Comment: I'm not really sure why a Fiddle is needed to demonstrate this... Just add `(function(i) {` at the beginning of the loop, and `})(i);` at the end... In what way is it "not working"?